# How can I get sub workflow steps/tasks output?

Tags: argo-workflows

I created a cluster workflow template, which will do some tasks. And I will use last step output as current workflow parameters. When I ref this template, I don't know how can I get the `output` from cluster workflow task/step.

**Cluster Workflow Template**

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterWorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: gen-params
spec:
  templates:
  - name: tasks
    steps:
    - - name: prepare
        template: prepare
    - - name: gen-params
        template: gen-params
...
```

**Workflow**

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
  - name: main
    steps:
    - - name: gen-params
        templateRef:
          name: gen-params
          template: tasks
          clusterScope: true
    - - name: calculate
        template: calculate
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: params
            value: "{{steps.gen-params.steps.gen-params.outputs.result}}"  # not work
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is likely less about the usage of a WorkflowTemplate/ClusterWorkflowTemplate and more to do with the fact that you are attempting to access output from a "nested" workflow step.

You can achieve this by defining an output parameter of the top-level `tasks` template in your ClusterWorkflowTemplate which takes its value from the output result of the last step in that `tasks` template.

Your WorkflowTemplate would look like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterWorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: gen-params
spec:
  templates:
  - name: tasks
    steps:
    - - name: prepare
        template: prepare
    - - name: gen-params
        template: gen-params
    outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: "nested-gen-params-result"
            valueFrom:
              parameter: "{{steps.gen-params.outputs.result}}"
```

After making that change, you'll be able reference the output of the ClusterWorkflowTemplate-defined step of your top-level Workflow using `{{steps.gen-params.outputs.parameters.nested-gen-params-result}}`

Argo's [nested-workflow example](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/f33624d67d0cf348dcdece46832081346c26bf80/examples/nested-workflow.yaml) shows some other similar patterns.

Comment: fyi that link is broken - think it's this one: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/nested-workflow.yaml

Answer (score 2):

`templateRef` is simply a link, used to populate the YAML of the Workflow step. You should interact with the `gen-params` step in the same way that you would if you'd just copy/pasted the YAML from the `gen-params` ClusterWorkflowTemplate directly into your new Workflow.

In this case, you should access the result of the `gen-params` step with this: `{{steps.gen-params.outputs.result}}`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
So you mean I can just use template `{{steps.???.outputs.result}}` which `???` is from ClusterWorkflowTemplate steps?

Comment: Kind of, but not exactly. You can use the template `{{steps.AAA.outputs.result}}` where `AAA` is the name of a step in your Workflow. That step can be defined in any way you want, including by referencing a step from a ClusterWorkflowTemplate. If the ClusterWorkflowTemplate step is called `BBB`, but it's referenced in your Workflow in a step called `AAA`, you would refer to the output in your Workflow with `steps.AAA`.

Comment: Think of your Workflow as having its own namespace. In that namespace, `steps.XYZ` refers to a step with the name `XYZ` _in the Workflow's namespace_. The Workflow can _import_ steps from other namespaces (Templates), but it only imports the step, not the name. The Workflow determines what the step will be called in the context of the Workflow.

Comment: I have the same issue with dags. using value: "{{tasks.persons-policies.outputs.parameters.generatedDatasetId}}" seems not to work and the argo server does not let me create the workflow